# Environment Variable on Vertex Ai

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I want to pass Environment Variable to Vertex Ai custom job. Can some tell like how to write that part ?

I want to pass Environment Variable to Vertex Ai custom job. Can some tell like how to write that part ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm double checking, but I think you can't declare custom environment variables to custom training jobs.

But you can pass those variables/information as arguments... As example, take a look into [this notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/ml_metadata/sdk-metric-parameter-tracking-for-custom-jobs.ipynb) and how argparse works at "Write the training script" and "Launch a custom training job" sections.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom training job is using a docker container, you can declare these variables inside your `Dockerfile`:

Example:

```
FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-gpu.2-10
LABEL MAINTAINER = "NAME (EMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM)"
ENV MY_ENV_VARIABLE = "some value"

# ... more commands like RUN or COPY

CMD python main.py # (or whatever your equivalent file is named)
```

You can learn more about `ENV` and `ARG` in Dockefiles [here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-time-env-values/) and [from the official docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement)

Alternatively, you can set environmental variables inside your `config.yaml` file under `containerSpecs`:

```
workerPoolSpecs:
  machineSpec:
    machineType: MACHINE_TYPE
    acceleratorType: ACCELERATOR_TYPE
    acceleratorCount: ACCELERATOR_COUNT
  replicaCount: REPLICA_COUNT
  containerSpec:
    imageUri: CUSTOM_CONTAINER_IMAGE_URI
    env:
      - name: MY_ENV_VARIABLE
        value: "some_value"
```

Any variables you add to that `YAML` file above will be passed to your container ([docs here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/CustomJobSpec#containerspec)). More information about creating these Vertex AI config files can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/create#--config).

It's also useful to know that Vertex AI sets a number of environments which it uses to decide where to store a model, among other things: [Variables set by Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/code-requirements#environment-variables)

---

**If you could provide some more details about your custom job**, I might be able to provide a better/more useful answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the 3 sdk such as AIP, KFP and TFX can define jobs' environment variables:

```py
job = aiplatform.CustomContainerTrainingJob(
        display_name="custom-job",
        container_uri=f"{GCR_DOCKER_PATH}",
    )

env_vars = {
    "BATCH_SIZE": "2048",
    "EPOCHS": "5",
    "PYTHONPATH": "/root_folder",
}

model = job.run(
    environment_variables=env_vars,
)
```

- assuming container image is hosted on a GCR Docker registry, and has functional purpose of a training job written in Python. The provided parameters are defining Python path for absolute import (simple approach without packaging) and hyperparameters for better batch runs in order to fine tune the AI model. Authentication might need Service Account access.

*Keep in mind writing pipeline mixing sdk with custom containers can be time consuming as these 3 sdk might not have equivalent for custom training job.*